# Update total based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple finance tracker app that I am working on. Within the app, there is a table of all outgoing bills and then a total figure that sits outside of the table.

I'm trying to find a way to use JS or AJAX so that when I select a checkbox within 1 of the table rows I can include/exclude the bill from the total and have the total automatically update to reflect the exclusion/inclusion.

The table rows are dynamically created so each time a new bill is added the rows increase which means the checkbox ID would need to increase.

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <table class="display table" style="width:100%" id="example">
    <thead class="table-heading">
      <tr class="table-border">
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">CREDITOR</th>
        <th scope="col">DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th scope="col">CATEGORY</th>
        <th scope="col">AMOUNT</th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">INCLUDE / EXCLUDE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for item in debts %}
      <tr class="table-border table-items">
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.creditor }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
        <td>£{{ item.amount }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" style="border:2px dotted #00f;display:block;background:#ff0000;" class="table-checkbox" id="myCheckbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've got this bit of JS

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    alert('checked');
  } else {
    alert('not checked');
  }
})
```

That does fire the alert when the checkbox is checked, but this only fires on the first checkbox as this is the checkbox with the same ID.

So this is probably a tricky task to solve, as I would need the checkbox JS to know what the amount is for the row the checkbox is checked for and then subtract that figure from the total or vice/versa. Maybe this is the wrong approach?

The total is displayed as:

```
<h3 class="text-right text-danger"><i class="mdi mdi-cube icon-size float-left"></i><span class="font-weight-bold">£{{total_monthly_outgoing|floatformat:2}}<span class="h6"> per month</span></span></h3>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to delegate

I had to unwrap your span in the h3 to not make very messy JavaScript

Give the total an ID to make it easier than `document.querySelector("h3.text-danger span")`.

You do not need IDs for this script

INCLUDE when checked

```js
const totalContainer = document.querySelector("h3.text-danger span");

document.querySelector(".card-body").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches(".table-checkbox")) return; // not a checkbox
  const total = [...document.querySelectorAll(".table-checkbox:checked")]
    .map(chk => +chk.closest("td").previousElementSibling.textContent.slice(1)) // remove the pound
    .reduce((a,b)=> a+b); // sum
  totalContainer.textContent = `£${total.toFixed(2)}`;
})
```

```css
.table-checkbox {
  border: 2px dotted #00f;
  display: block;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <table class="display table" style="width:100%" id="example">
    <thead class="table-heading">
      <tr class="table-border">
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">CREDITOR</th>
        <th scope="col">DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th scope="col">CATEGORY</th>
        <th scope="col">AMOUNT</th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">INCLUDE / EXCLUDE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-border table-items">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>creditor 1</td>
        <td>description 1</td>
        <td>category 1</td>
        <td>£123</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-border table-items">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>creditor 2</td>
        <td>description 2</td>
        <td>category 2</td>
        <td>£223</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-border table-items">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>creditor 3</td>
        <td>description 3</td>
        <td>category 3</td>
        <td>£323</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h3 class="text-right text-danger"><i class="mdi mdi-cube icon-size float-left"></i><span class="font-weight-bold">£0</span><span class="h6"> per month</span>
  </h3>

</div>
```

EXCLUDE when checked

```js
const totalContainer = document.querySelector("h3.text-danger span");
let total = [...document.querySelectorAll(".table-checkbox")]    
  .map(chk => +chk.closest("td").previousElementSibling.textContent.slice(1)) // remove the pound
  .reduce((a,b)=> a+b); // sum

document.querySelector(".card-body").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches(".table-checkbox")) return; // not a checkbox
  const val = +tgt.closest("td").previousElementSibling.textContent.slice(1);
  total +=  val*(tgt.checked ? -1 : +1)
  totalContainer.textContent = `£${total.toFixed(2)}`;
})
```

```css
.table-checkbox {
  border: 2px dotted #00f;
  display: block;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <table class="display table" style="width:100%" id="example">
    <thead class="table-heading">
      <tr class="table-border">
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">CREDITOR</th>
        <th scope="col">DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th scope="col">CATEGORY</th>
        <th scope="col">AMOUNT</th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">INCLUDE / EXCLUDE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-border table-items">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>creditor 1</td>
        <td>description 1</td>
        <td>category 1</td>
        <td>£123</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-border table-items">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>creditor 2</td>
        <td>description 2</td>
        <td>category 2</td>
        <td>£223</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-border table-items">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>creditor 3</td>
        <td>description 3</td>
        <td>category 3</td>
        <td>£323</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h3 class="text-right text-danger"><i class="mdi mdi-cube icon-size float-left"></i><span class="font-weight-bold">£669.00</span><span class="h6"> per month</span>
  </h3>

</div>
```

Comment: That's so good. Thanks. Is it possible to make it just subtracts from the total if the checkbox is checked? So total already shows the total value, if I check the box it will subtract, and then if uncheck it puts it back?

Comment: See updated script